# New published work denied brewski robbery

Tags: cryptic-clues

Cryptic crossword clue: *New published work denied brewski robbery (4,2)*

The answer is ‘hold up’ but I don't know why? I'm not understanding where this answer is coming from in the clue.

Synonyms for brewski?

Work can be represented by ‘op’

I can’t see it!

Comment: TIL the word "brewski".

Answer (score 14):

Here's the analysis:

> New published work denied brewski robbery (4, 2)
>  New is an anagrind
>  denied is a subtraction indicator
>  "robbery" is the definition
>  An anagram of (PUBLISHED WORK) is (HOLDUPBREWSKI)
>  Subtracting BREWSKI, we get HOLD UP

Answer (score 12):

So the answer is

> HOLD UP

Because

> You take the letters in PUBLISHED WORK, and you remove the letters in BREWSKI from that; you get PU L  H D  O. Then I’m assuming “new” clues a rearrangement, and the letters PULHDO rearrange to HOLD UP, with definition “Robbery”